# ios 10 web browser fixed position break when <select> is active

Tags: ios10

In ios 10, in all browser (safari, chrome, firefox) I noticed that when a `<select>` tag is active, the rest of the page is fixed.

This conflict with elements having css property `position:fixed` or `position:sticky`while they are fixed, resulting a progressive disapearing related to the scrolling position of the page.

This appear only for `<select>` tag that have a native rendering. I could not reproduce the issue with `<select>` having custom rendering due to some plugin.

Did you see this issue ? Maybe in other case ?
Is there any css property available to avoid this ?

EDIT : [webkit bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162362)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have linked to a bug report in which is stated that it's a bug which will hopefully be fixed soon. This leaves nothing more to be answered here.

Comment: I'm asking for a temporary solution.

Comment: Actually all input element conflict with some fixed position.